# SQL field default "count(another_field) +1"

Tags: sql, count, create-table

I need to create a field COUNT whose default value is the automatically generated count of times NAME has appeared in that table till now, as shown in example below. Since i am adding the field to an existing table, i also need to populate existing rows. How best to go about this please?

```
ID  NAME    COUNT
1   peter   1
2   jane    1
3   peter   2
4   peter   3
5   frank   1
6   jane    2
7   peter   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this when you are querying the table, using the ANSI-standard row-number function:

```
select id, name, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I would like to be able to query the table based on that column, e.g. where COUNT=1, so i'd rather have it as a field

Comment: @lidram . . . You don't need to add another field to get the minimum id for a `name`.

Comment: For anyone out there using this, i tried using a WHERE clause but that's not allowed "Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses". So i am copying the data to a new table and selecting from there.

Comment: @lidram . . . You could probably just use a subquery.